# .htaccess How to redirect some specific pages, then a blanket rule to new domain?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, 301-redirect

I am creating a new website on a new domain, and doing page-to-page redirects from the old website for **(A)** all static pages, as well as **(B)** all blog posts.

**A)** The static pages follow a new URL categorization and naming pattern, eg.

`http://olddomain.com/doctors/` becomes `https://newdomain.com/about-us/team/`

**B)** The rest are a whole bunch of blog posts that will keep the same URL pattern, they are `/postname/`, so I just need to map them to the new domain in the root. Eg.

`http://olddomain.com/hello-world-blog-post/` becomes `https://newdomain.com/hello-world-blog-post/`

Here is an example of what I tried (didn't work):

```
# 1. Redirect to domain without www
# ... This is if people try www.olddomain.com, or there are links out there pointing to this
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# 2. 301 Redirect URLs
Redirect 301 /doctors/ https://newdomain.com/about-us/team/
Redirect 301 /us/ https://newdomain.com/about-us/
#etc...

# 3. Redirect to another domain: newdomain.com
# ... This is to send http://olddomain.com/hello-world-blog-post/ to https://newdomain.com/hello-world-blog-post/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

## What Happened?

When I tried testing by visiting `http://olddomain.com/doctors/`, rather than catching the `Redirect 301` rule (`Redirect 301 /doctors/ https://newdomain.com/about-us/team/`), it simply redirected to the new domain, ie, `https://newdomain.com/us/`, which of course generated a 404 page not found error on the new domain.

So it seems to be ignoring the 2nd batch of rules and just doing the 3rd.

Comment: PS - I used http://beamusup.com/generate-htaccess/ to generate this, FYI!

Comment: Mixing mod_alias rules (`Redirect`) with mod_rewrite rules (`RewriteRule`) can lead to precedence problems.   Have you tried using all rewrite rules?

Comment: Are `olddomain.com` and `newdomain.com` pointing to the same host? If so then presumably you have more directives in your `.htaccess` file (ie. some kind of front-controller that routes your blog posts)? Please post your entire `.htaccess` file. Even accounting for the mix of mod_alias and mod_rewrite directives that @Stephen noted, there is nothing in what you've posted that would perform the redirect you are reporting (ie. `http://olddomain.com/doctors/` to `https://newdomain.com/us/`)? In fact, none of the above actually redirects HTTP to HTTPS at all?

Comment: How does `lighthousehealth.ca` fit into your `olddomain.com` / `newdomain.com` example? I think you may have exemplified your rule(s) incorrectly in your question? The last rule would result in a redirect loop. Also make sure you clear your browser cache and test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid the browser cache giving you additional grief.